# Google script - Hide/Unhide google sheet based on checkbox on another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I"m pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in the code, as to why it's not functioning the way I want it. Firstly, here's the code:

```
function onEdit(a) {

var sheet = a.source.getActiveSheet();
var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var COMP = aa.getSheetByName("COMP");
var COMPcell = sheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
if(COMPcell = 'TRUE'){COMP.showSheet();}else{COMP.hideSheet();}
}
```

In here, I have a checkbox on cell B6 of the 'active sheet' (named Monthly summary). When checked (and thus have a value of TRUE), I want the sheet named "COMP" to appear. Otherwise, it should be hidden. I'm not really good at coding and I've researched the above formula and modified it as to my requirement, but I can't get it to work.

Any insights on this will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If ``COMP`` sheet is hidden and when the checkbox is checked at the cell "B6", the sheet is shown by the simple trigger of OnEdit event. I think that your script works. So can I ask you the detail information about ``I can't get it to work.``?

Comment: @Tanaike, it's working initially, as long as the COMP sheet is hidden and checkbox is unchecked. So when I check the box, COMP sheet appears. However, when I uncheck the box, it doesn't disappear. Likewise, when COMP sheet is hidden but checkbox is checked, when I uncheck the box, COMP sheet appears, which it shouldn't. I wish to have the sheet be shown as long the box is checked, but not shown when the box is checked. I created a test file to demonstrate the problem here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXHT5p6i6jQJzZEggy0-xs3cnmVAnBvMkPgOlppCp0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the sample Spreadsheet. I proposed the modified scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to show the sheet of `COMP` only when the checkbox of "B6" is checked.
- You want to hide the sheet of `COMP` when the checkbox of "B6" is not checked.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script 1:

If your script is modified, in your script, `COMPcell = 'TRUE'` of the if statement is not compared the value. In this case, please modify to `COMPcell === true`. The modified script reflected this is as follows.

```
function onEdit(a) {
  var sheet = a.source.getActiveSheet();
  var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var COMP = aa.getSheetByName("COMP");
  var COMPcell = sheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
  if (COMPcell === true) { // Modified
    COMP.showSheet();
  } else {
    COMP.hideSheet();
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

When the event object and `isChecked()` are used, your script can also be modified as follows. In this script, only when the checkbox of "B6" is edited, the script works.

```
function onEdit(a) {
  var range = a.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() == "B6") {
    var COMP = a.source.getSheetByName("COMP");
    if (range.isChecked()) {
      COMP.showSheet();
    } else {
      COMP.hideSheet();
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isChecked())
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: thanks for this! The 1st modification worked but I haven't really checked on 2nd modification. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @J.Mapz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.